# Error: unexpected symbol in very long R row

Tags: r

I have a very long row in my R code. Very long is about 24.813 characters in a row. The structure of this row looks like

```
x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, [...], 4317, 4318, 4319)
```

Directly under this line is a similar line which is shorter, because it only contains integers:

```
y = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1 [...], 1, 0, 1)
```

This throws an error:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in: 
", 790, 791, 792, [...], 825, 826, 827,
y"
```

The value `790` is approx at position 3.844. I have double checked: There is nothing unusual at this position.

**QUESTION: Is there a maximumm length for a line in R?**

**EDIT**
I guess what @Roland suggests was the dirty solution I was looking for. Line breaks made it work. And yes, I know I should have read the data from a file :-) Thank you all!

Comment: Could the error be referring to the `y`?

Comment: could you do sanity check with `class(y)` if it's indeed integers.

Comment: You will need to trouble-shoot this at your end: remove everything that is non-essential, i.e. shorten the code progressively until the error disappears. That way you will be able to isolate the issue.

Comment: Put line breaks in this row (after some commas). And in the future, put these numbers into a file and read the file from R.

Comment: Where did this row come from?  Further,   if an element of `y` is actually `3.844`  ( `3,844` in USA notation), then what you have is a character string and not a numeric value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Maximum line length

According to the R Core Team manual, [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc),

> Command lines entered at the console are limited<sup>4</sup> to about 4095 bytes (not characters).

The relevant footnote says:

> some of the consoles will not allow you to enter more, and amongst those which do some will silently discard the excess and some will use it as the start of the next line.

This behaviour seems inconsistent across IDEs. I just created a line of >220k ASCII characters (so >220k bytes) and was able to parse it in VS Code.

```
# real version repeats this string until it is over 220k characters long
nchar(
    "very_long_string_very_long_string_very_long_string_very_long_string_"
)
```

VS Code output:

```r
[1] 221760
```

But I tried the same line in RStudio and it could not handle it. RStudio output:

```
tringvery_long_stringvery_long_stringvery_long_string"
+ )
+ 
+
```

RStudio seems to be exhibiting the behaviour in the footnote and silently discarding the excess (including the close quote). As *An Introduction to R* says:

> If a command is not complete at the end of a line, R will give a different prompt, by default `+` on second and subsequent lines and continue to read input until the command is syntactically complete.

In any case, despite being in an R manual, the issue seems to be IDE related. I tested whether VS Code could handle lines over 1m characters in length (so over 1mb) and it can. Perhaps another reason to use VS Code, if one was needed, though I can't think of a good reason to have a line that long in code.

#### Maximum vector length

There is also a maximum length for a vector which depends on whether you're using 32/64 bit R, the R version and the type of vector. It's probably 2^52-1 elements for an integer or numeric vector with a reasonably modern R version on a computer that isn't very old. See [Long vectors](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Long-vectors) in R Internals.

Comment: Could be, but I wonder whether `y[1:790]`  would ever be long enough to meet those limits.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft who knows whether this is the cause of the issue. I was answering what had been asked: is there a maximum row length for a line in R?